# HTML5 Canvas: draw large number of lines faster

Tags: javascript, html, performance, 3d, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a small 3D engine (in HTML5) from scratch just for the experience and I have run into a problem. The engine is currently only displaying the edges of models, which is what I want it to do, but it runs extremely slow compared to WebGL, which obviously deals with much more. I can get only about 4800 lines to display before a frame-rate drop becomes noticeable, which is 400 cubes.

I believe the bottleneck is with the drawing of the lines.

> I tested this by drawing one cube (to view smoothness) but calculating for all cubes. I can get about 10,000 cubes to compute (without actually drawing the lines) before any lag presents itself. I know drawing to the screen normally where bottleneck occurs.

The thing that I think separates me from webGl speed wise is the lack of graphics card use. I don't know the back-end of canvas but I am guessing that I am not using any power from the graphics card.

So I was wondering if there is a faster method to display the lines or if this is something that I will just have to accept.

*P.S. I do not want to use any external API's, I want this to be complete ground up. I am not making this to distribute it so performance doesn't matter. I am just trying to learn how engines work and play around at the lowest level of 3D graphics.*

Comment: Use debugger tools to determine if your page is being recalculated too often and narrow down the problem (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3pxf3Ju2row)

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean by that. The problem comes from
`ctx.beginPath();`
`ctx.moveTo(vert1.drawx,vert1.drawy);`
`ctx.lineTo(vert2.drawx,vert2.drawy);`
`ctx.stroke();` Which take too long to draw.

Comment: Developer tools can help you determine why its taking too long to draw - test the timings and determine what the page is trying to do when its rendering your lines. For example, if you're page is doing a ton of recalc styles or similar calculation try to batch them together. Checkout some of the #perfmatter talks on optimizing and debugging ui updates

Comment: Are you using a separate beginPath for each line? You can do multiple moveTo+lineTo within a beginPath/stroke for better performance.

Comment: @markE That was the problem, it is much faster now. 5000 cubes and very little lag! Thanks :D